# I am learning Fortran on Code::Blocks IDE, i dont know how to install libraries

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, libraries

I am learning Fortran on Code::Blocks IDE but I can not find how to use libraries like stats, standard library, or similar. How can I use libraries? I couldn't find any tutorials.
Thanks

Comment: What libraries do you refer to?  Oh, and don't spend time looking for a Fortran *standard library*, there isn't one.

Comment: There is actually a package manager called `fpm` and a library project *std-lib* but it is still somewhat limited. Definitely worth to try, though. Just don't expect you will find all you need there. You need to look around if something that you need exists. See https://fortran-lang.org/en/ and https://github.com/fortran-lang/fpm and https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib

Comment: There is no standard set of libraries that you could install in a single system like Anaconda for Python or Julia or similar. Fortran is more like C. Many various libraries exist and you have to find the library that suits you and find out how it is used. No truly standardized library like the C++ STL.